# Pickle dump replaces current file data

Tags: python, pickle

When I use pickle, it works fine and I can dump any load.

The problem is if I close the program and try to dump again, it replaces the old file data with the new dumping. Here is my code:

```
import pickle
import os
import time


dictionary = dict()


def read():
    with open('test.txt', 'rb') as f:
        a = pickle.load(f)
    print(a)
    time.sleep(2)


def dump():
    chs = raw_input('name and number')
    n = chs.split()
    dictionary[n[0]] = n[1]
    with open('test.txt', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(dictionary, f)


Inpt = raw_input('Option : ')
if Inpt == 'read':
    read()
else:
    dump()
```

Answer (score 20):

When you open a file in `w` mode (or `wb`), that tells it to write a brand-new file, erasing whatever was already there.

As [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) say:

> The most commonly-used values of mode are 'r' for reading, 'w' for writing (**truncating the file if it already exists**), and 'a' for appending…

In other words, you want to use `'ab'`, not `'wb'`.

---

However, when you append new dumps to the same file, you end up with a file made up of multiple separate values. If you only call `load` once, it's just going to load the first one. If you want to load *all* of them, you need to write code that does that. For example, you can `load` in a loop until `EOFError`.

---

Really, it looks like what you're trying to do is not to append to the pickle file, but to *modify* the *existing* pickled dictionary.

You could do that with a function that loads and merges all of the dumps together, like this:

```
def Load():
    d = {}
    with open('test.txt', 'rb') as f:
        while True:
            try:
                a = pickle.load(f)
            except EOFError:
                break
            else:
                d.update(a)
    # do stuff with d
```

But that's going to get slower and slower the more times you run your program, as you pile on more and more copies of the same values. To do that *right* you need to load the old dictionary, modify that, and then dump the modified version. And for that, you *want* `w` mode.

However, a much better way to persist a dictionary, at least if the keys are strings, is to use [`dbm`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dbm.html) (if the values are also strings) or [`shelve`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) (otherwise) instead of a dictionary in the first place.

Answer (score -2):

Opening a file in `"wb"` mode truncates the file -- that is, it deletes the contents of the file, and then allows you to work on it.

Usually, you'd open the file in append (`"ab"`) mode to add data at the end. However, Pickle doesn't support appending, so you'll have to save your data to a new file (come up with a different file name -- ask the user or use a command-line parameter such as `-o test.txt`?) each time the program is run.

On a related topic, don't use Pickle. It's unsafe. Consider using JSON instead (it's in the standard lib -- `import json`).

Comment: The first half of your answer is right… but the second half is not. Pickle does support appending. And as for "unsafe", if you're trying to save types besides float/str/list/dict, JSON can't do it, unless you extend it, in which case it becomes exactly as unsafe as pickle. You have to know your data and how you want to store it, or there is no general safe answer.

Comment: No. Pickle is inherently dangerous (as the module's documentation takes great care to warn against, several times), and `pickle.load` *will execute arbitrary code contained in the pickled file*: http://michael-rushanan.blogspot.ca/2012/10/why-python-pickle-is-insecure.html

Comment: If you don't even attempt to understand why pickle is dangerous, you're going to end up writing code that's just unsafe using extended JSON or otherwise. What the warning specifically says is "The pickle module is not intended to be secure against erroneous or maliciously constructed data." If you extend JSON to store and restore custom classes in the obvious way, it will be just as insecure against erroneous or malicious constructed data.

Comment: More generally: `pickle` is obviously not a silver bullet that solves all problems. But it's also not a completely useless module that should never be used. If it were, it wouldn't be in the standard library. Spreading FUD about it for no reason does no one any good.